# Need help in sed with using a template to create new files for virtual hosts

Tags: bash, awk, sed

```
for j in `cat server_name_list`; do sed -i 's/DIR/${j}/g' dlist1 &gt; $j.conf; done
```

Basically I am trying to create a number of apache virtual hosts using one virtual host file as a template....

so, template file:
cat /tmp/dlist1

```
Allow From All
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/DIR
ServerName DIR.com
ServerAlias www.DIR.com
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm
ErrorLog "logs/DIR_com_error_log"
CustomLog "logs/DIR_com_access_log" common
```

And the list of servers is in a file

```
cat /tmp/server_name_list
abc.com
xyz.com
utv.com
```

so the sed script has to give me three files as in abc.conf, xyz.conf, utv.conf

with this content(just writing the one for "abc" here):

```
Allow From All
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/abc
ServerName abc.com
ServerAlias www.abc.com
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm
ErrorLog "logs/abc_com_error_log"
CustomLog "logs/abc_com_access_log" common
```

Comment: As the bash tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.". One you fix the issues that shellcheck tells you about then let us know if you still have a problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
for j in `cat server_name_list`; do
  j="${j%.*}"
  sed "s/DIR/$j/g" dlist1 > $j.conf;
done
```

Explanation:

- `j="${j%.*}` uses parameter expansion to remove the `.com` extension from the server name. The syntax `${j%.*}` means to remove the shortest match of `.*` (i.e., ".com") from the end of the string `j`.
- `sed "s/DIR/$j/g" dlist1 > $j.conf` replaces all occurrences of the string `DIR` in the dlist1 template file with the current server name `j`
- The output of the `sed` command is redirected to a file with the name `$j.conf`.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

First you [DRLWF](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

A solution with a `while` + `read` loop. Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -ru "$fd" servers; do
  sed "/^\(ServerName\) .*/s//\1 $servers/" dlist1 > "${servers%.*}"
done {fd}< server_name_list
exec {fd}<&-
```

---

- Adjust/use the absolute path for the files in use.

Answer (score 0):

I would GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `temp.txt` content be

```
Allow From All
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/DIR
ServerName DIR.com
ServerAlias www.DIR.com
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm
ErrorLog "logs/DIR_com_error_log"
CustomLog "logs/DIR_com_access_log" common
```

and `list.txt` content be

```
abc.com
xyz.com
utv.com
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[.]";RS="";getline template < "temp.txt";RS="\n"}{print gensub(/DIR/,$1,"g",template) > $1 ".conf";close($1 ".conf")}' list.txt
```

creates files

```
abc.conf
utv.conf
xyz.conf
```

content of 1st of them is

```
Allow From All
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/abc
ServerName abc.com
ServerAlias www.abc.com
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm
ErrorLog "logs/abc_com_error_log"
CustomLog "logs/abc_com_access_log" common
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that literal dot is field separator (`FS`) then I turn off paragraph mode by setting `RS` to empty string, but only during usage of [`getline`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fVariable_002fFile.html) so it would read everything up to first blank line, then I set `RS` to newline, so it would work in typical manner. Then for each line I do use [`gensub`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function, I do not need capturing group there, but I use it as I want `template` variable value to stay untoched, after replacing all (`g`) `DIR` occurences with 1st column value I `print` it into file of corresponding name and `close` that file.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & parallel):

```
parallel sed 's/DIR/{.}/g' templateFile \> {.}.conf :::: serversFile
```

For each line in the serversFile, apply the changes to the templateFile and save the results in a separate file.

N.B. The `{.}` returns the line from the serversFile less the extension e.g. `abc.com` becomes `abc`.